# What is the best practices for image handling in cakephp 3?

Tags: php, image, cakephp, upload, cakephp-3.0

I'm developing a project using cakephp 3. Now, I'm looking for the following solutions.

1. What is the proper way to check image exists or not? If not, then show image-not-found.jpg. Now I'm checking in view by `file_exists` functions. It seems to me that it is using repeated codes. Is't possible to set from model? So that, there will be no headache from view.
2. When I store images outside of img folder. Then I usually show images by `'../'.$img_url`. What is the best practice for this?
3. Which one is best plugin/behavior for cakephp 3 to upload images with crop & thumb options?

Comment: Check https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/awesome-cakephp for list of existing plugins for file upload and image resizing.

Comment: Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create new Helper or virtual properties on entities and within it check for pictures.
2. Show images outside img folder `echo $this->Html->image('/myOutSideFolder/myimage.jpg');`
3. Implement your own, use http://image.intervention.io/ or http://imagine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ to process the photos.